# Query for Fetching data from MySQL grouped by data in two columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure like following:

[image: Department table]

I am trying to write a query to show total employees for **one department** using dept_id like this:

[image: Output table for dept_id 1]

The category names are getting fetched using joins from another table:
Category table has following fields:

id | Cat_Name

I am trying to do the same using Group by

Following are my tries on MySQL queries: (Presently i am not using joins as I know I can fetch the category name using join later).

I am concerned with how to fetch the data in the above shown format.

1. SELECT * FROM `dept_data` WHERE dept_id = 1 GROUP BY year
2. SELECT * FROM `dept_data` WHERE dept_id = 1 GROUP BY year, category_id

Anyone who can help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Its called `pivot`, and unfortunately `mysql` doesn't provide this functionality. Search for **mysql pivot** and you can have some workarounds to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Shaharyar wrote in the comments, it's called "pivot".

You need a conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT year AS Year,
    MAX(CASE WHEN category_id = 1 THEN total_employees END) AS `Category 1 (Name)`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN category_id = 2 THEN total_employees END) AS `Category 2 (Name)`
FROM dept_data
WHERE dept_id = 1
GROUP BY year
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for response, however I couldn't use your query because it is returning as error #1064.

Comment: I have tried different conbinations with your query:

Comment: I have come up with a modified version of your query and it works. I am posting it below as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @paulspiegel

Comment: @NeelkanthKaushik sorry,  i missed the `END` in `CASE` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came up with a query that does what I needed.

Thanks to Paul Spiegel.

It is actually just a modified version of Paul Spiegel's answer.

```
SELECT year AS Year, 
MAX(IF(category_id = 1, total_employees, NULL)) AS Category1,
MAX(IF(category_id = 2, total_employees, NULL)) AS Category2
FROM dept_data WHERE dept_id = 1 GROUP BY year
```

I hope it will help someone else too.